# Duplicate misspelled tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

There should be just `photon-emission` but there is also a misspelling of the tag.
[image]

How does one go about reporting this?

Answer (score 8):

Fixed.

In general, to report minor things like misspellings, etc, which do not require that the community should make a decision of principles, but it is clear what needs to be done, then one could just mention the problem in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).

Comment: Understood, thanks.